# How do I Stop Angular from Clearing the Text Selection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to render and refresh every few seconds a list of complicated objects using Angular. An issue I've found is that when the refresh happens, even if a particular HTML subcomponent hasn't changed, the HTML is updated and if you'd selected some of the text (e.g. you were trying to copy it) the selection goes away.

I know there is a general issue with changing the html that contains a selection, but I'm wondering if Angular has some solution to the problem that I'm just not aware of. Basically what I'm looking for is for only the HTML that actually changed being updated. I could do that if I was writing view code manually in jQuery, but every other part of doing it manually is awful

JS:

```
angular.module('items', [])
.factory('itemList', ['$http', function($http) {
  var items = [];
  var refresh = function() {
    // imagine that this makes an HTTP call to get the new list
    // of items
    items.length = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      items.push("item " + Math.random(1, 10))
    }
  }
  refresh();
  return {
    items: items,
    refresh: refresh
  };
}]);


var app = angular.module('app', [
  'items'
]);

app.controller('ItemListController',
  ['$scope', 'itemList', '$interval',
  function($scope, itemList, $interval) {
    this.items = itemList.items;
    $interval(itemList.refresh, 2000)
  }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="ItemListController as controller">
  <h3>Items</h3>
  <div ng-model="active">
    <div ng-repeat="item in controller.items">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div>{{item}}</div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're wholesale replacing itemList on each refresh, angular has no option but to re-create all the elements in the ng-repeat, which is fine if you don't mind losing the selection and the refresh isn't too large and expensive. To prevent this though, you could try writing a merge in that factory that diffs the previous against the new and adds/removes items without replacing the whole reference. Then only if the item you selected no longer exists would you lose the selection.

Also, if the list is long and the differences from refresh to refresh are small, then this will probably be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

$interval refreshes entire DOM So selection is get refreshed and new value will appear.
  if you want to select then cancel the interval for particular time $interval.cancel(milliseconds) then restart the timer with selected range.

```
$scope.$watch("refresh", function(){
           $interval.cancel(5000);
          p = $interval(itemsList.refresh(), 2000);
        })
```

Comment: I don't really want to cancel the refresh, I want to avoid updating the parts of the DOM that haven't changed so that if the user was in the process of trying to copy some text the selection won't go away. I could potentially disable the refresh during the selection, but if they didn't unselect the UI would stop updating

Comment: It shouldn't by angularjs since it happened binding

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thor's answer was on the right track. The issue was that I wasn't using "track by FOO" on my [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), so it had no way of knowing that the elements in my actual case with complex objects were the same and thus it redrew them